# How to improve fetching speed and reduce time from api using python?

Tags: python, json, performance, api

I want to fetch some data from api but it takes longer time to fetch data from url.

```
import json
import urllib.request
from datetime import datetime
def home():
    print(datetime.now())
    total=urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.covid19api.com/summary')
    total.encoding='UTF-8'
    data=json.loads(total.read())
    Total=data['Global']['TotalConfirmed']
    print(datetime.now())

home()
```

output

```
2020-05-08 12:12:24.715765
2020-05-08 12:12:53.998154
```

Comment: I don't think there's a faster way to do so tbh - although I think [this](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2893714/improving-web-api-performance.html) may help.

Comment: You're probably experiencing network problems. On my machine is does not take more than 0.2 s (with >80% of the time spent to fetch data from url). Check first your network latency, then your bandwidth. Note that if the problem is the bandwidth, this may be improved.

Comment: My network speed is above 1 mbps but still facing that problem.